# Вывести информацию с максимальными значениями после count

Tags: mysql, count, max

Есть задача - вывести всю информацию о сотрудниках, обслуживших больше всего клиентов (мобильные номера).

Информация по сотрудникам хранится в таблице Staff (StaffID, Surname, Given, DOB и тд), информация по обслуженным номерам хранится в таблице Mobile (MobileID, PhoneNumber, StaffID, CustomerID)

Для начала я посчитал сколько всего номеров обслужено по каждому сотруднику и даже могу понять сколько именно максимально номеров на одного сотрудника приходится (таких сотрудников 2е)

```
select max(x.served_customers) as maxc 
from (
    select s.StaffID, s.Given, s.Surname, count(m.StaffID) as served_customers 
    from staff s
    left join mobile m on m.StaffID = s.StaffID
    group by s.StaffID 
    ) x
```

но вот как вывести всю инфу я не могу понять.

если использую where после nested query - получаю ошибку что таблицы X не существует.

если добавить в первую строку остальные аттрибуты я получу просто результат вложенного запроса, но если Добавить having x.surved_customers = maxc после group by Staff id - тоже получаю ошибку. необходимо решить задачу с помощью простейших команд.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbieq.jpg - таблица staff
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8VYQ.jpg - таблица mobile

Comment: Вот тут https://stackoverflow.com/a/74209009/10138734 решается аналогичная задача, но для двух максимальных. Используй - для одного ещё проще.

Comment: у меня проблема с тем, что что бы я не пробовал после nested для вывода числа обслуживаемых номеров на каждого сотрудника, кидает ошибку. where, having говорят что они понятия не имеют что это за таблица, которая получилась после nested quiery

Comment: и я не должен использовать limit, только агрегаты и вложенные запросы.

Comment: select sc.* from (
select s.StaffID, s.Given, s.Surname, count(m.StaffID) as served_customers from staff s
left join mobile m
on m.StaffID = s.StaffID
group by s.StaffID ) SC
natural join (
 select distinct max(sc.served_customers) as maxs
    from sc
    group by sc.StaffID
    order by max_sc DESC ) max_sc
    попробовал как в примере - результат предсказуемый, результат первого агрегата - таблица sc неизвестна

Comment: Ну если делать не так. как советуется, то результат и правда предсказуем. С какого перепугу во втором подзапросе `FROM sc`?

Comment: *я не должен использовать limit, только агрегаты и вложенные запросы* В случае "только максимум" это решается без LIMIT - просто обернуть второй подзапрос ещё подзапросом, чтобы получить максимум максимумов.

Comment: еще раз что б получить количество из которого вообще можно брать максимум нужно сделать вложенный запрос с count. любые операции с таблицей полученной входе этого подзапроса кидают ошибку кроме селекта

Comment: Делайте online fiddle cо своими структурой и данными. А то пальцами в воздухе можно вертеть до-о-олго..

Comment: давайте по шагам : я делаю подзапрос с count что б получить  количество по которому мне вообще надо считать максимум.  дальше что я не понимаю? обернуть этот подзапрос что бы получить максимум? ок. дальше то мне как сравнивать значения если одно лежит как агргат в сабкваери на 3 м уровне, максимум на втором уровне

Comment: Добавил скрины с таблицами и дынными

Comment: Зря. [Почему в вопросе не следует выкладывать скриншоты кода/данных/ошибок?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119) См. [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169), особенно пункты 5, 3 и 2.3.